# How can I replace a key mapping in a Tree Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, tree, key

Ok, so here is a class I have written for a two-key database. I've completed a number of methods but I am having trouble getting what I want for the change methods. The problem is that I successfully create either a new KeyOne of KeyTwo that maps to the correct data, but the previous keyOne or KeyTwo will also map to that value. So for example,

```
db.add(68, 15, "Christian"); // Firsy key, second key, data
db.add(66, 100, "Mario");
db.add(14, 31, "Ernest");
db.add(20, 10, "Paul");

//Testing of the change methods.
db.change1(20, 11);
System.out.println(db.key2Find(11));
System.out.println(db.key2Find(10)); //error 10 should not map anymore
OUTPUT:
Paul
Paul
```

There can only be one keyOne and one KeyTwo per data.

Here, is a portion of my code. The change1 and change2 methods are the ones I'm having trouble with. How can I go about this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class TwoKey<k1 extends Comparable, k2 extends Comparable, D>{

private TreeMap<k1,D> key1Map = new TreeMap<k1, D>();
private TreeMap<k2,D> key2Map = new TreeMap<k2, D>();
public D dataGarbage;

 public void add(k1 keyOne, k2 keyTwo, D data){
 //Add data to the database, accessible by two keys.
 //Each key is mapped to one data value, but key 1 and key 2 are in seperate mappings.
  key1Map.put(keyOne, data);
  key2Map.put(keyTwo, data);
}
public D key1Find(k1 keyOne){
//Search the database using key one and return the data associated with it.
  return key1Map.get(keyOne);
}
public D key2Find(k2 keyTwo){
//Search the database using key two and return the data associated with it.
  return key2Map.get(keyTwo);
}
/* Modifying works by storing current data in the dataGarbage instance
 * variable, then making the first data change, 
 * then modifying the other keylist by finding the other key associated with it, 
 * then applying the second data change */
public void modify1(k1 keyOne, D newData){
  if(keyOne == null){
    Set set = key1Map.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
      Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
      if(me.getValue() == dataGarbage){
        key1Map.put((k1)me.getKey(), newData);
      }
    }
    return;
  }
  dataGarbage = key1Map.get(keyOne);
  key1Map.put(keyOne, newData);
  modify2(null, newData);
}
public void modify2(k2 keyTwo, D newData){
  if(keyTwo == null){
    Set set = key2Map.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
      Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
      if(me.getValue() == dataGarbage){
        key2Map.put((k2)me.getKey(), newData);
    }
  }
  return;
} 
dataGarbage = key2Map.get(keyTwo);
key2Map.put(keyTwo, newData);
modify1(null, newData);
```

}

```
 public void change1(k1 keyOne, k2 keyTwo){
  //Change the second key associated with the data corresponding to keyOne,to keyTwo
  D k1Data = key1Map.get(keyOne);

D k1Data = key1Map.get(keyOne);

Set set = key1Map.entrySet();
Iterator i = set.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
  Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
  if(me.getValue() == k1Data){
    key2Map.remove(me.getKey());
    key2Map.put(keyTwo, k1Data);
  }
}   

 }
   public void change2(k2 keyTwo, k1 keyOne){
    //Change the first key associated with the data corresponding to keyTwo, to KeyOne

  D k2Data = key2Map.get(keyTwo);

   Set set = key2Map.entrySet();
   Iterator i = set.iterator();
   while(i.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    if(me.getValue() == k2Data){

      key1Map.put(keyOne, k2Data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, `change1()` doesn't **\*DO\*** anything.  All you do is get from what appears to be a Map.  Maybe an actual attempt at writing some code here would help.

Comment: Just added the code for the first change1, forgot it when I created this!

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What I don't understand is you change key1, but then say key2 should map any more.  That makes no sense.  Why should key2 not map when you only change key1?

Comment: Look at what the other guy is trying. I'm using the first argument to get the data, then changing the second key associated with that data to keyTwo. The problem is the old KeyTwo still maps to the data and I don't want it to.

Comment: So changing key1 also changes key2?  Always?  That seems weird but I guess it's at least algorithmic

Comment: Not exactly, I just need to find the data associated with the keyOne argument. Then I'm changing that data's second key. His code below deletes the first key, i'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: How is your statement different than mine?  If you're changing the data's second key, how does that not mean "if key1 changes key2 always changes?"

Comment: I just posted a solution, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your change1 as follows:

```
     public void change1(k1 keyOne, k2 keyTwo){
       //Change the second key associated with the data corresponding to
       //keyOne,to  keyTwo
       D k1Data = key1Map.get(keyOne);
       Iterator<Map.Entry<k1,D>> i = key1Map.entrySet().iterator();
       while(i.hasNext()){
         Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
         if(me.getKey().equals(keyone){
            i.remove();
         }     
       }
       key2Map.put(keyTwo, k1Data);
   }
```

Comment: the me.remove() gives me a cannot find symbol error

Comment: For some reason I still get both 10 and 11 still mapping to Paul, my outpull should be Paul, null but instead it's Paul, Paul

Comment: Still getting Paul, Paul! Geez this must be so resilient! haha

Comment: Nope, had to add a parenthesis and change keyone to keyOne. But it is still giving me Paul Paul when I try to print the key associated with 10, which should be getting removed

Comment: hey I actually just noticed that KeyOne is being deleted after calling the change1 method instead of the original keyTwo. When I tried to do a key1Find for "20" null came up. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @ChristianRoss , I hope you got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out for those interested.

Slight change to the solution given by @Steephen.

```
   public void change1(k1 keyOne, k2 keyTwo){      
    D k1Data =  key1Map.get(keyOne);
     Iterator<Map.Entry<k2,D>> i = key2Map.entrySet().iterator();
      while(i.hasNext()){
       Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
        if(me.getValue().equals(k1Data)){
        i.remove();
        }     
      }
   key2Map.put(keyTwo, k1Data);
   }
```

Had to iterate over the second key map(key2Map), find the same data equivalent to k1Data, and then remove the mapping at that index key of iteration.